# Why '===' does not check if the values are the same or not

Tags: typescript

I have a Image object with the method `getPixel`

> getPixel(img: Image, x: number, y: number): Color

where Color is an array of numbers that represent the color values of the given pixel like

> type Color = [r: number, g: number, b: number]

When I call the line `getPixel(img, 5, 5);` with an Image object `img` where its a 10x10 red canvas and each pixel value is `[255, 0, 0]`, I get the value `[255, 0, 0]`

I am trying to compare this value to `COLORS.RED` which is also equal to `[255, 0, 0]` with `getPixel(img, 5, 5) === COLORS.RED` and I get `false` all the time. Why are they not equal and if `===` is checking if its pointing at the same variable how can I make sure that it checks if the values are the same?

Comment: `its pointing at the same variable` are you sure they are both pointing to same variable? Or they are just pointing to 2 different arrays that have the same amount of elements with the same values?

Comment: @SergeySosunov I said "if === is checking if its pointing at the same variable" so I know they are not pointing at the same variable and they are two different arrays.

Comment: Honestly I'd use lodash isEquals method, less headache. But if it is mandatory for you to use == or === operators - you will need to create some kind of data-container, static class or global array, that will hold all the used colors combinations you are interested in. And from this single container you will need to populate (using find, or indexes) results for `getPixel` calls and COLORS.RED. Like const RED = allColorsArray.find(x => x[0] === 255 && x[1] ===0 && x[2] === 0). So that will guarantee that they will be comparable in a way you want. Something like that.